# What does my friend need?

Tags: riddle, visual

I arrive home to a note from my friend. It is not signed from anyone, it just has these pictures at the bottom.

> Image 1
>   [image: Image 1]
>   
>   Image 2
>   [image: Image 2]
>   
>   Image 3
>   [image: Image 3]

Ahh, okay this is from my friend, Astor. He's a bit strange. The note says he wants me to get something from the store, but again all he has are these images.

> Image 1
>   [image: Image 1]
>   
>   Image 2
>   [image: Image 2]
>   
>   Image 3
>   [image: Image 3]
>   
>   Image 4
>   [image: Image 4]

**What does Astor want me to get?**

To address a few comments, the lack of information regarding the images was part of the intention.

**Hint:**

> I won't give the word associated with the image because I think it will make it too easy.

Comment: Ya' know, "enter image description here" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the typo find, and yes I had never used images before wasn't sure what those were for. @Pheo However, these images aren't meant to have a description with them. Part of the riddle is figuring out what the image is meant to be.

Comment: @Colton "Image of dog sled" "Image of Memo"

Comment: Does the note contain any written text (outside of any images)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Astor wants you to buy

> Noodles

"Astor" may have come from

> **A**pple**S**
>  s**T**o**O**p
>  pu**R**se
>  ...taking the letters first from the outside-then 1 place in from each end-then 2 places in from each end.

Applying this to the second set of pictures we have

> **N**em**O**
>  n**O**bo**D**y
>  de**LE**te (picture is a "delete" icon)
>  dog **S**led

Comment: Well done!! Your answer and all the explanation behind it is 100% correct. I accepted it.

Comment: @Colton Thanks, great puzzle. Chowzen did most of the work with his/her breakthrough, so thanks to you, and I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

So, I think that "Astor" came from

> [**A** pples](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1093&bih=539&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ApjoWqWYOsLVzgLWk4noCg&q=apples&oq=apples&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.29551.31194.0.31424.6.6.0.0.0.0.99.491.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.487...0i67k1.0.bxqnKs9DkSE)
>  [**St** oop](https://www.google.com/search?q=stoop&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjByOjK-eTaAhWJvlMKHTEHA2UQ_AUICigB&biw=1093&bih=539)
>  [**Or** ganizer](https://www.google.com/search?q=wallet+organizer&oq=wallet+or&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.11096j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Now I need to apply that to the rest. Is this the right track?

Comment: First two words are correct, but the third one is incorrect. Also, the way you derived "Astor" from the words is on the right track, but not totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but is this to do with...

> Bad lip reading?

I'm guessing this because...

> "Apples door" mouthed silently looks like your friend's name "Astor". I think with the first three picture you are showing us how you realised who the note is from.

But I can't figure out:

> what, if anything "Nemo nobody bin husky" could look like. Tried miming it to my wife and she just thinks I'm (more) crazy.

Comment: +1 for creative answer, but not quite on the right track unfortunately. Although, you are correct in your reasoning about the 3 images. This will be key in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Astor wants you to get

> Fish for nobody to eat but to throw to the dogs.

Comment: So I don't think you're on the right track with this one. All of the images in the question will be important in determining what Astor wants from the store.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very) partial answer:

> He wants something from the Apple Store (Apples, Door)

Answer (score 0):

> Dusk nobody plush? 
>  **du** from dustbin 
>  **nobody** from nemo & the no"body" image 
>  **plush** from furry dogs.

Answer (score -2):

> Find somebody to take the trash out?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Could you add a bit of explanation to your answer?

Comment: Hey @Sidhi Gupta, try referencing my comments on other answers and the hint I provided for some more guidance.